# Python Twisted sending large a file across network

Tags: python-2.7, networking, twisted

I am trying to send a file across the network using Twisted with the LineReceiver protocol.  The issue I am seeing is that when I read a binary file and try to send the chunks they simply don't send.

I am reading the file using:

```
import json
import time
import threading
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import protocol

MaximumMsgSize = 15500

trySend = True
connectionToServer = None

class ClientInterfaceFactory(protocol.Factory):

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return WoosterInterfaceProtocol(self._msgProcessor, self._logger)

class ClientInterfaceProtocol(LineReceiver):

    def connectionMade(self):
        connectionToServer = self

    def _DecodeMessage(self, rawMsg):
        header, body = json.loads(rawMsg)   
        return (header, json.loads(body))

    def ProcessIncomingMsg(self, rawMsg, connObject):
        # Decode raw message.
        decodedMsg = self._DecodeMessage(rawMsg)

        self.ProccessTransmitJobToNode(decodedMsg, connObject)

    def _BuildMessage(self, id, msgBody = {}):
        msgs = []

        fullMsgBody = json.dumps(msgBody)
        msgBodyLength = len(fullMsgBody)

        totalParts = 1 if msgBodyLength <= MaximumMsgSize else \
            int(math.ceil(msgBodyLength / MaximumMsgSize))

        startPoint = 0
        msgBodyPos = 0

        for partNo in range(totalParts):
            msgBodyPos = (partNo + 1) * MaximumMsgSize

            header = {'ID' : id, 'MsgParts' : totalParts,
                'MsgPart' : partNo }
            msg = (header, fullMsgBody[startPoint:msgBodyPos])
            jsonMsg = json.dumps(msg)       

            msgs.append(jsonMsg)
            startPoint = msgBodyPos

        return (msgs, '')

    def ProccessTransmitJobToNode(self, msg, connection):
        rootDir = '../documentation/configs/Wooster'

        exportedFiles = ['consoleLog.txt', 'blob.dat']
        params = {
            'Status' : 'buildStatus',
            'TaskID' : 'taskID',
            'Name' : 'taskName',
            'Exports' : len(exportedFiles),
            }
        msg, statusStr = self._BuildMessage(101, params)
        connection.sendLine(msg[0])

        for filename in exportedFiles:
            with open (filename, "rb") as exportFileHandle:
                data = exportFileHandle.read().encode('base64')

            params = {
                ExportFileToMaster_Tag.TaskID : taskID,
                ExportFileToMaster_Tag.FileContents : data,
                ExportFileToMaster_Tag.Filename : filename
            }
            msgs, _ = self._BuildMessage(MsgID.ExportFileToMaster, params)          
            for m in msgs: 
                connection.sendLine(m)

    def lineReceived(self, data):
        threads.deferToThread(self.ProcessIncomingMsg, data, self)


def ConnectFailed(reason):
    print 'Connection failed..'
    reactor.callLater(20, reactor.callFromThread, ConnectToServer)

def ConnectToServer():
    print 'Connecting...'
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
    endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, 'localhost', 8181)

    deferItem = endpoint.connect(factory)
    deferItem.addErrback(ConnectFailed)

netThread = threading.Thread(target=reactor.run, kwargs={"installSignalHandlers": False})
netThread.start()

reactor.callFromThread(ConnectToServer)

factory = ClientInterfaceFactory()
protocol = ClientInterfaceProtocol()

while 1:
    time.sleep(0.01)

    if connectionToServer == None: continue

    if trySend == True:
        protocol.ProccessTransmitJobToNode(None, None)
        trySend = False
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?file is sent, it's when the write is multi part or there are more than one file it struggles.

If a single write occurs then the m
Note: I have updated the question with a crude piece of sample code in the hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_BuildMessage` returns a two-tuple: `(msgs, '')`.

Your network code iterates over this:

```
msgs = self._BuildMessage(MsgID.ExportFileToMaster, params)

for m in msgs:
```

So your network code first tries to send a list of json encoded data and then tries to send the empty string.  It most likely raises an exception because you cannot send a list of anything using `sendLine`.  If you aren't seeing the exception, you've forgotten to enable logging.  You should always enable logging so you can see any exceptions that occur.

Also, you're using `time.sleep` and you shouldn't do this in a Twisted-based program.  If you're doing this to try to avoid overloading the receiver, you should use TCP's native backpressure instead by registering a producer which can receive pause and resume notifications.  Regardless, `time.sleep` (and your loop over all the data) will block the entire reactor thread and prevent any progress from being made.  The consequence is that most of the data will be buffered locally before being sent.

Also, your code calls `LineReceiver.sendLine` from a non-reactor thread.  This has undefined results but you can probably count on it to not work.

This loop runs in the main thread:

```
while 1:
    time.sleep(0.01)

    if connectionToServer == None: continue

    if trySend == True:
        protocol.ProccessTransmitJobToNode(None, None)
        trySend = False
```

while the reactor runs in another thread:

```
netThread = threading.Thread(target=reactor.run, kwargs={"installSignalHandlers": False})
netThread.start()
```

`ProcessTransmitJobToNode` simply calls `self.sendLine`:

```
def ProccessTransmitJobToNode(self, msg, connection):
    rootDir = '../documentation/configs/Wooster'

    exportedFiles = ['consoleLog.txt', 'blob.dat']
    params = {
        'Status' : 'buildStatus',
        'TaskID' : 'taskID',
        'Name' : 'taskName',
        'Exports' : len(exportedFiles),
        }
    msg, statusStr = self._BuildMessage(101, params)
    connection.sendLine(msg[0])
```

You should probably remove the use of threading entirely from the application.  Time-based events are better managed using `reactor.callLater` (your main-thread loop effectively generates a call to `ProcessTransmitJobToNode` once hundred times a second (modulo effects of the `trySend` flag)).

You may also want to take a look at https://github.com/twisted/tubes as a better way to manage large amounts of data with Twisted.

Comment: The message being sent isn't a list, it's a Json dumps() output.  I return a list of messages, but for looping through them

Comment: Yes, yes it should.

Comment: Nope, changed and removed sleep ...  still not working?  As data is binary should it be raw mode?

Comment: You can't have binary data in a JSON blob.

Comment: Why are you inventing your own protocol for this?  Try using something simple and standard like HTTP.

Comment: Since this is only a program fragment it's not really possible to explain why it doesn't work.  See http://sscce.org/

Comment: I know it's not a complete fragment, a full example would have been long.  I read that you can send binary via Jason if you base64 encode it, which is what I am doing??

Comment: After you encode it to base64, it's no longer "binary".  "Binary" is a terrible word but basically it just means "may contain bytes greater than 127 and maybe some bytes from the control area of ASCII".  A base64 encoded string never contains any such bytes nor does a JSON encoded string.  So such strings are perfectly safe to use with `LineReceiver.sendLine`.  The problem lies elsewhere.  Also, a "full" example won't be too long - you just have to trim the parts that don't _matter_.  For example, most of _BuildMessage is probably not relevant to the problem at and and could be deleted.

Comment: Updated to include a basic example of what I am trying to do

Comment: okay, answer updated to point at the likely real cause: threading.

Comment: I have removed all threading from the application and use reactor.callLater(0.5....) to call ProccessTransmitJobToNode but still only seeing 1st message - is my 'encoding' causing issues?

Comment: Maybe you can open a new question with the new code.

Comment: Closing as  with your help to solve the other issues it turned out to be buildmessage function at fault... but I wouldn't have got to this point without you.  Thank you.